Azure DevOps Branch Policies
I have a question on branch policies in Azure DevOps, Can we get Pipeline status from Repo B to the branch policies of Repo A? I tried setting it directly and it didn't work as expected and can we achieve using rest Api's or anything and post in branch policies?
Thanks in advance.
I tried setting it directly and it didn't work as expected and can we achieve using rest Api's or anything and post in branch policies?

Branch policy is the configuration of the branch, which doesn't have any pipeline status. Can you elaborate a bit of get Pipeline status from Repo B to the branch policies of Repo A? Are you not able to list the pipeline from repoB in the branch policy setting? Or cannot get the pipeline result of repoB in repoA Pull request? Is the pipeline from RepoB in same project?

I mean to say pipeline status checks in Pull requests.
I am able to list it, But it is not pulling any data. Repo B is in same project.

we can use the rest api to update the pull request status check, please check the script below, put it in the pipeline from Repo. Let me know if you have any queries.

To update the status check in the pull request, you can use rest api Pull Request Statuses
Powershell sample:
# Define variables
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "project"
$repositoryId = "repoid"
$pullRequestId = "336"
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Define the API URL
$apiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/statuses?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

# Define the status check details
$statusCheck = @{
    "state" = "succeeded"  # Possible values: "notSet", "pending", "succeeded", "failed", "error"
    "description" = "All checks passed"
    "context" = @{
        "name" = "codecoverage"
        "genre" = "aspnetwebappwithtest1"
    }
}

# Convert the status check details to JSON
$statusCheckJson = $statusCheck | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3

# Create the authorization header
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Send the POST request to update the status check
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $statusCheckJson

# Output the response
$response



